# Decorate a Shopware 6 core service without modifying the abstract class

Tags: symfony, shopware, shopware6, symfony5

After decorating a `Shopware 6 core service` and adding a `new method`, how do you use the call up the new method. I am not allowed to modify Shopware 6 bundle code base.
Example:

```php
//abstract class begins
abstract class AbstractCoreService
{
  public function doSomething();
}
//abstract class ends


//service class begins
class CoreService extends AbstractCoreService
{
  public function doSomething(){
    return 'I did Something'
  }
}
//service class ends


//decorator begins
class CoreServiceDecorator extends AbstractCoreService
{
    public function doSomething(){
     return 'I did Something More';
    }

    public function doSomethingElse(){
     return 'I did Something Else';
    }
}
//decorator ends
```

How do I use the method `doSomethingElse`? I get an **undefined method error** code Editor.

Below is my `xml` file code. PS, I followed this Shopware 6 guide  [Docorate A Service](https://developer.shopware.com/docs/v6.4/guides/plugins/plugins/plugin-fundamentals/adjusting-service.html)

```xml
        <service id="AbstractCoreService" id="CoreService" />

        <service id="CoreServiceDecorator" decorates="AbstractCoreService">
        </service>
```

Here is me using the `doSomethingElse` method of the `CoreServiceDecorator` class.

```php
use AbstractCoreService;

class DoRunService extends AbstractCoreService;
{
 
 private AbstractCoreService $coreService;

 __construct(AbstractCoreService $coreService)
 {
   $this->coreService = $coreService; 
 }

 public function doSomething(){
  return $this->coreService->doSomething();
 }

 public function doRun(){
  return $this->coreService->doSomethingElse();
  //here the error message from my code Editor is `undefined method`
 }

}
```

The `xml` file includes

```xml
 <service id="DoRunService">
  <argument id="AbstractCoreService" type="service">
 </service>
```

Comment: "I get an undefined method error code Editor" - what does that mean? Can you share the full and exact error message? As far as I can see, you don't even all `doSomethingElse` in the code you've shared

Comment: do I inject the `CoreServiceDecorator` or `CoreServiceDecorator` or `AbstractCoreService`  inorder to use `doSomethingElse()` method?

Comment: As a start: you forgot to put the `CoreService` into the decorated service. Additionally, when decorating, you still inject the original service (as the service container handles the decoration internally, and injects the decorated service where the original service was injected before)